# Disable iOS video controls for youtube video

Tags: javascript, iphone, video, web, youtube

My goal is to present clients with a video from youtube (iframe api) that cannot be skipped or seeked forward. On all platforms but iOS this is simple. But I'm having problems with Apple's fullscreen player.

Once playback on a video has started, you are transported to Apple's iOS video player, with it's standard controls. What I have been unable to find is if you can hide/disable these controls in the fullscreen layout.

Alternatively, if I can capture events from the iOS player and merely detect when a user is trying to skip would work as well. I've attached events in accordance with the HTMLMediaElement specs, but none of them fire. Nor do any of youtube's events fire.

I am tracking the console through Safari from the iOS simulator, which could be a problem on it's own.

Any help would be appreciated. I've gone through every SO post on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was unable to find anyway to hide the iOS default viewer (I believe it's impossible), I was able to get the youtube events to fire. With keeping an interval, and checking that against the video's time each time an event is fired, I can figure out if a user has skipped.